# Hibernate - load children

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following Hibernate Mappings:

```
<class name="Database.Content" table="..." schema="" catalog="...">
    <id name="id">
        <column name="id" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
    </id>
    <property name="week">
        <column name="week" sql-type="int"/>
    </property>
    <property name="day">
        <column name="day" sql-type="int"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hour">
        <column name="hour" sql-type="int"/>
    </property>
    <property name="type">
        <column name="type" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="group" class="Database.Group">
        <column name="group"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="table" class="Database.Table">
        <column name="table" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <list name="entries" inverse="true" table="...">
        <key>
            <column name="content" not-null="true"/>
        </key>
        <list-index column="id"/>
        <one-to-many not-found="ignore" class="Database.Entry"/>
    </list>
</class>
<class name="Database.Entry" table="..." schema="" catalog="...">
    <id name="id">
        <column name="id" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
    </id>
    <property name="teacher">
        <column name="teacher" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="course">
        <column name="course" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="room">
        <column name="room" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="p">
        <column name="p" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="content" class="Database.Content" fetch="join" lazy="false">
        <column name="content" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

Now I am trying to query all `contents` with the corresponding `entries`:

```
List<Content> contents = session.createQuery("from Content c WHERE c.day IN :days ").setParameterList("days", days).list();
```

The query returns the correct response. However, when I do the following:

```
contents.get(0).getEntries()
```

there is a bunch of null values. What is the correct way to eager load all corresponding `entries` for each `content`?

I have about 20,000 `content` records, and most of the records have only one entry.

If I set `lazy="false"` for the list of `entries`, I get `Java heap space` error.

---

I ended up fetching `entries` and joining `contents`:

```
List<Entry> entries = session.createQuery("select e from Entry e Join e.content c WHERE c.day IN :days ").setParameterList("days", days).list();
```

I also changed `lazy` to `proxy` in:

```
<many-to-one name="content" class="Database.Content" fetch="join" lazy="proxy">
    <column name="content" not-null="true"/>
</many-to-one>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add lazy=false attribute:

```
 <list name="entries" inverse="true" table="up_timetable_entries" lazy="false">
```

Hope helped you!

Comment: Thanks. I have about 20,000 `content` records, and most of the records usually have only one entry. But it takes forever now to load them, so I cannot tell if it works now.

Comment: I get the following error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: I believe that 20.000 elements is too much. You have to delete the lazy=false and call the contents.get(0).getEntries() inside the Hibernate Context

Comment: Thanks, but then I get a bunch of nulls

Comment: I wonder if I could just get the result of joining two tables into the Java application, and then query the result for `contents` and `entries`

Comment: I think that you get nulls because you call the getEntries method outside the DAO. Try call it after the query.getResult.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling:

contents.get(0).getEntries().size();

To force hibernate to load the children.

Comment: The result is always a number that is much much larger that expected